# How to label lines with cytoscape.js?

Tags: javascript, topology, cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape.js to generate a visual network topology. Is there a way to display additional data (e.g. network interfaces) on the nodes themselves or on the connections between nodes? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two visual styles immediately come to mind:

1. Background images on nodes
2. Arrow shapes on the edge terminals

Do either of these meet your usecase, or is there something more specific you could describe that you're looking for?

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your response. Ideally we would need something like http://img42.com/EWN6E. Is this possible with cytoscape? Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like you want labels on the source and target ends of the edge https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/382